# Windows 7 only IE working other browsers not

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, internet

I have strange behavior with browsers on my PC (but it work well before yesteday)
My Chrome, FF `(ERROR: Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): Unknown Error )` write me that can't connect to Internet I need to check Proxy, Firewall etc.
I did it and all settings are fine, on other PC in this area all working with the same settings. Only explorer can work in internet. How to solve it ?
Thanks
I have tried `chrome://net-internals/#tests` in grope and test `gooogle.com` but all test failed with `101 error`

Comment: Have you tried rebooting?

Comment: yes I have reboted Router and PC

Comment: What error message(s) are you seeing?

Comment: ERROR: Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): Unknown Error

Comment: Do you need to configure IE in any special way normally?  This sounds like both Firefox and Chrome are set to use a proxy basedon the error.

Comment: No I use all default settings  for IE. I have tried to swith on/off automatic proxy detection in proxy setting but result is the same IE works other not. I am using nod32 I also have disable firewall but it also not a solution. and it very strange yesterday all had working good